# Issues with Facebook Login using the SDK in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, firebase

EDIT: So, in my appdelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```

I had

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

after my

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

for some inexplicable reason, it gave the following error code:

```
message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
type = OAuthException;
```

which was from facebook, but if I comment out firebase, it all seems to work fine? No clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your access token is expired, you can check it over here also:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Get the current token and put it over there and check what you are getting. If not working then delete the app and reinstall and check.

**Edit**

Login with your facebook credential on above link which you are using to login inside app. You can get the access token over there by pressing gettoken button. Then compare your token with this token.

Comment: Cool thanks I'll check that out. but if it is expired, I need to delete the app where? within xcode or on facebook dev?

Comment: Yes from device or simulator.

Comment: what's weird is I have an older build on my phone, and that logs in just fine still

Comment: so where you are facing issue? inside simulator?

Comment: still getting the error now that I deleted it, and launched it again :(

Comment: the error is occurring in both simulator and on my iPhone 6S. clearly it's somehow, for one reason or another ,not getting a new token? I really don't know.

Comment: Follow this link and check what you are doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967036/facebook-sdk-for-ios-access-token-issue/34115509

Comment: that link is outdated, I'm using swift 3 on xcode beta 10, and I followed facebook's directions to a tee, again, it was working just fine a few days ago, I made no changes to the app whatsoever, and when I opened to work on it, I am getting this error now?

Comment: Bhadresh thanks for the second linke, but I have already seen that, and I am not making that same mistake.

Comment: Okay bro I am finding something. If I got anything then send you.

Comment: Okay so the culprit was "FIRApp.configure()", if I comment that out in my appDelegate it works fine. Any ideas why lol? I kind of need it during this progression.

Comment: Bro actually i havn't worked withe firebase. so no idea about that. I am speechless here.